# XCode 4.5 Fails to Archive Phonegap Project

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova

Im trying to Archive a Phogap project using XCode 4.5 but whenever I do I'm getting the error: `Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1`  Has anyone ever experienced this error before? If so, how can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the error mentions something about '3 Slices' none containing armv7s .

Goto Your Project > Build Settings > Remove 'armv7s' from 'Valid Architectures'
in both your project and the phonegap project as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for Xcode 4.5:

The fix is by removing the armv6 architecture from both your project and the CordovaLib project, clean
both projects, and rebuild.

[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1497)